# "set -m" command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I was going through a shell script where `set -m` was used.
My understanding is that `set` is used to get positional args.

For ex: `set "SO community is very helpful"`. Now, if I do `echo $1`, I should get `SO` and so on for $2, $3...

After checking the command with help flag, I got "-m   Job control is enabled."

My question is, what is the purpose of `set -m` in the following code?

```
set -m 
(
    current_hash="some_ha54_one"
    new_hash=$(cat file.txt)

    if [ $current_hash -ne new_hash ]; then
        pip install -r requirement.txt
    fi

    tmp="temp variable"
    export tmp

    bash some_bash_file.sh &
    
    wait
    
    bash some_other_bash_file.sh &
)
```

I understand (to the best of my knowledge) what I going on inside `()` but what is the use of `set -m` ?

Comment: Have you reviewed `help set`? It includes the following line: `-m  Job control is enabled.`

Comment: ...mind, there's no good reason for your script to be using job control at all. For that matter, `foo & wait` is in general quite silly; in most cases, you can and should just change it to `foo`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes I have checked ```help set```

Comment: ```&``` should make the bash file run in background. right? There is some DL model that is being trained through that script.

Comment: Right, but `wait` then waits for all background jobs to finish before proceeding. Putting something in the background and then waiting for it to finish is _almost_ identical to not putting it in the background at all.

Comment: Is the question really "what is job control in bash?"? Because you clearly _do_ know that `set -m` turns on job control; if the question is about why someone would want that, it might be worth editing to ask it more specifically.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, If I remove ```set -m ``` from the script  will it still function the same?

Comment: BTW, naming bash scripts with `.sh` is an antipattern. Best to make your script an executable (with a shebang that lets it choose its own interpreter) and not give it any extension at all; see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/, which has been linked from [the #bash IRC channel's factoid on the topic](https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh) for well over a decade.

Comment: Yes, the code you showed here will function the same without `set -m`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy will checkout the link. thanks

Comment: (keep in mind that bash scripts are not sh scripts, and `sh yourscript` turns off -- if it's bash -- or simply doesn't offer, if it's ash or dash -- a bunch of shell features; so naming scripts that need bash with `.sh` extensions can lend itself to people running them with an interpreter that doesn't provide the features they need).

Comment: One point re: "still function the same" -- if you want your script to emit messages about which PID each background job has, like `[1] 12345` to say that job 1 was started in the background with PID 12345, that's a job control feature, though of course you can use `$?` to collect the PIDs and log them yourself. (The `1` means you can use `%1` to refer to that same job; there's no equivalent to that with the feature disabled).

Comment: `set` has many purposes. It sets positional arguments only when there are arguments besides the options. From the bash man-page: _Any arguments  remainin after  option  processing  are treated as values for the positional parameters and are assigned_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Job control" enables features like `bg` and `fg`; signal-handling and file-descriptor routing changes intended for human operators who might use them to bring background tasks into the foreground to provide them with input; and the ability to refer to background tasks by job number instead of PID. The script segment you showed doesn't use these features, so the `set -m` call is presumably pointless.

These features are meant for human users, not scripts; and so in scripts they're off by default. In general, code that attempts to use them in scripts is buggy, and should be replaced with code that operates by PID. As an example, code that runs two scripts in parallel with each other, and then collects the exit status of each when they're finished *without* needing job control follows:

```
bash some_bash_file & some_pid=$!
bash some_other_file & some_other_pid=$!
wait "$some_pid"; some_rc=$?
wait "$some_other_pid"; some_other_rc=$?
```

Comment: can you please direct me to a link for a good use case (preferably small) of ```set -m ```.  or maybe dd that in you answer

Comment: There are quite a lot of behavior changes (search for "job control" in `man bash`), but they're pretty much all focused on interactive use and not meaningful to scripts. I'm more likely to use `set +m` to _disable_ job control to enable the `lastpipe` feature than I am to ever enable it... but if I'm doing that in code that's `source`d into an interactive shell, then I would want to use `set -m` when the function that needs `lastpipe` exits to turn it back on.